# bxslider custom pager with style

Tags: javascript, html, css, bxslider

I have one problem, I need do this:
http://oi40.tinypic.com/21dj2ms.jpg

I tryed do this, here is the code:

```
$('#slider-three').click(function(){

   slider.goToSlide(3);
   return false;

});


<a href="" id="slider-three">Vladimír Slezák</a>
```

But how can I set A LINK to active?
Other link have the same background color, but the active link must have different color, how can I do this?

Something like this 
"If you are on slide 2, set background color of second a.link to black"

Do someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to reference the a.active class supplied by bxSlider.

CSS example:

```
#bx-pager li a.active, 
#bx-pager li a:hover {
background-color: #4C5B60;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/defonic/ZZSH8/

Comment: Tak you so much! :)

I think that most important thiks to do it is this : content:' (Active)';